# Error while pulling a container image

Tags: docker

I'm getting the below error while I'm trying to pull an image from a know registry:

> `root@devesh:/home/deahuja3# docker pull [ip]:5001/[name1]/[name2]:81
>   Pulling repository [ip]:5001/[name1]/[name2]:81
>   dd7baca1069d: Error pulling image (81) from [ip]:5001/[name1]/[name2], Error mounting '/dev/mapper/docker-202:2-6382377-2eaf0096818bb22255f7e4a8487d159eaf895339a62ed36d03c77bcdd48a052d' on '/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2eaf0096818bb22255f7e4a8487d159eaf895339a62ed36d03c77bcdd48a052d': invalid argument 36d03c77bcdd48a052d': invalid argument
>   FATA[0004] Error pulling image (81) from [ip]:5001/[name1]/[name2], Error mounting '/dev/mapper/docker-202:2-6382377-2eaf0096818bb22255f7e4a8487d159eaf895339a62ed36d03c77bcdd48a052d' on '/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2eaf0096818bb22255f7e4a8487d159eaf895339a62ed36d03c77bcdd48a052d': invalid argument`

Docker Version:

> `root@devesh:/home/deahuja3# docker version
>   Client version: 1.6.2
>   Client API version: 1.18
>   Go version (client): go1.4.2
>   Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
>   OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
>   Server version: 1.6.2
>   Server API version: 1.18
>   Go version (server): go1.4.2
>   Git commit (server): 7c8fca2
>   OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64`

Docker Info:

> `root@devesh:/home/deahuja3# docker info
>   Containers: 0
>   Images: 0
>   Storage Driver: devicemapper
>    Pool Name: docker-202:2-6382377-pool
>    Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
>    Backing Filesystem: extfs
>    Data file: /dev/loop0
>    Metadata file: /dev/loop1
>    Data Space Used: 305.7 MB
>    Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
>    Data Space Available: 103.5 GB
>    Metadata Space Used: 733.2 kB
>    Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
>    Metadata Space Available: 2.147 GB
>    Udev Sync Supported: false
>    Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
>    Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
>    Library Version: 1.02.82-git (2013-10-04)
>   Execution Driver: native-0.2
>   Kernel Version: 3.13.0-51-generic
>   Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
>   CPUs: 4
>   Total Memory: 7.829 GiB
>   Name: devesh
>   ID: [id]
>   WARNING: No swap limit support`

The same pull command used to work earlier. 
How to overcome this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: Dummy question: "Are you just typing <docker pull> without specify the image?"

Comment: Nope, I'm providing the image registry also with it. eg: docker pull 10.9.12.1:5001/myimage:latest

Comment: can you pull from docker hub?

Comment: Hi @VincentDeSmet, my machine works in a private network only, so I can't pull any image from docker hub. But there are another images, which I'm able to pull successfully. I'm seeing this issue with a specific image on my specific machine. The same image is getting pulled successfully on other machines.

Comment: strange, re-install docker on your machine?

Comment: @VincentDeSmet simple re-install wasn't solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was with the device mapper.

The issue was resolved by doing the following steps:

1. service docker stop
2. remove the whole of `/var/lib/docker` folder
3. Re-install docker
4. reboot

Thanks.